# OpenSSL how to request client certificate, but don't verify it

Tags: c++, c, linux, openssl, certificate

I want to setup openssl c/c++ server request certificate from client but don't verify it.

I already use this piece of code to query certificate from client:

```cpp
/** Force the client-side have a certificate **/
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, nullptr);
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
```

Can anybody give me example of such server code?

Comment: A better title for your question would be probably something like: "OpenSSL how to request client certificate, but ignore it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html). It states:

> `void SSL_CTX_set_verify(SSL_CTX *ctx, int mode, SSL_verify_cb verify_callback);`
>
> [...]
>
> The return value of verify_callback controls the strategy of the further verification process. If verify_callback returns 0, the verification process is immediately stopped with "verification failed" state. [...] If verify_callback always returns 1, the TLS/SSL handshake will not be terminated with respect to verification failures and the connection will be established. [...]

Writing a function that always returns `1` and passing it as `verify_callback` should help you solve the problem.

Comment: I have another problem now. I think data that client sends to the server does not encrypt (i can see all data in wireshark)

Comment: I'm sorry it's my fault (i'm sending data twice)